# Retrieve CursorAdapter with activeAndroid and SearchView

Tags: android, searchview, android-cursoradapter

I try to implement a "android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" into my toolBar who should provide some suggestions to the user.

I wished [activeAndroid](http://www.activeandroid.com/) could provide me a way to retrieve a CursorAdapter directly from my query (basically a getAll()).

The [following link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/activeandroid-guide#populating-listview-with-cursoradapter) seems to be deprecated since .toSql() require private access and "Cache" is unresolved.

Any idea?

Comment: the problem is that you dont show any connection between entered search text and the executed query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Cursor via ActiveAndroid using:

`Cursor cursor = ActiveAndroid.getDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE", null);`

The CursorAdapter you will need to build yourself but is quite easy and the "Defining the Adapter" section of the link you provided should give you what you need to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that ActiveAndroid 3.1.0 does show the .toSql() as public.

One thing you will need to do is make sure your ActiveAndroid db model includes the expected _id column which is not there by default with ActiveAndroid.  You'll want to uninstall the app or perform a database migration to see the changes to the underlying db model.  Otherwise you may get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

Include the expected '_id' column which is not there by default with ActiveAndroid:

```
@Table(name = "Items", id = BaseColumns._ID)
```

Request the cursor like this:

```
public Cursor getCursor() {
    String sql = new Select()
            .from(Item.class)
            .toSql();
    String[] params = null;
    Cursor cursor = Cache.openDatabase().rawQuery(sql, params);
    return cursor;
}
```

You could then create an adapter like this:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        c, new String[] {"Name"}, new int[] { android.R.id.text1}
);
```

Comment: Event if both works good, finally this seems to be the best solution, Thanks